# Prove/disprove $A\cap B=A\cap C $ for every $A$ $\iff B=C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Let $A,B,C$ be sets, prove/disprove: $A\cap B=A\cap C $ for every  $A$ $\iff B=C$

I think it's wrong, choose $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{2,3\}, C=\{2,4\}$ so $A\cap B=A\cap C$ but $B\neq C$

Although it's a bit strange to see "for every  $A$" in the middle of an iff statement...

Can I choose $B,C$ like I did?

Comment: remember it has to be for EVERY A

Comment: Do you mean to prove: $(A\iff B=C)\to (A\cap B=A\cap C)$?

Comment: If it confuses you you can rewrite it formally as

"Prove $(\forall A,\, A\cap B=A\cap C)\iff B=C.$" if you really want the quantifier to be at the start, but it's important it be attached to the clause that uses it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose $A=B$ then $A=C$ and use that $X\cap Y=Y\cap X$.

These together say

> $$B=B\cap C,\quad C\cap B = C\qquad \implies B=(B\cap C)=(C\cap B)=C$$

Comment: Wait so why I can't choose $B,C$ like I did?

Comment: @kuhaku you can pick $B,C$, but you showed only that when they are not equal there is some $A$ so that $A\cap B\ne A\cap C$. If it were false you would have $B\ne C$ **and** $A\cap B=A\cap C$. Notice the two statements are different, yours has a not equals, but the problem would require an equality.

Comment: I showed the other side: $A∩B=A∩C$ but $B\neq C$...

Comment: @kuhaku you only showed it for one single $A$, you need it to be true for ALL $A$ (remember the quantifier). In particular, if you pick $B,C$, I am allowed to pick any $A$ I want to prove the direction $(\implies)$ since the hypothesis is that the intersection is true for every $A$.

Comment: But isn't it enough to show one counter example in order to disprove a $\forall$ statement?

Comment: Because your condition has to be fulfilled for every $A$, so take $A=\{4\}$ and it isn't. Therefore your choice is wrong.

Comment: I got it now, thanks Adam and user.

Answer (score 2):

No. The equality must hold for every set $A$.

If $A \cap B = A \cap C$ for every set $A$, then in particular $B = B \cap B = B \cap C$ so that $B \subset C$. Similarly $C = C \cap C = C \cap B$ so that $C \subset B$, implying $B = C$.

Comment: Why is $B=B∩B\color{red}{=}B∩C$?

Comment: You are assuming that $A \cap B = A \cap C$ for **every** set $A$.  In particular if $A = B$ it will be true that $B \cap B = B \cap C$.